# Shuffle Inputs to Keras Model Independently

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, shuffle

I'm training a CNN to classify time series of two different lengths, 40 timesteps and 80 timesteps. I've created a Siamese Neural Network to train the network on both at the same time (as I cannot create a batch of two different size inputs). I'm trying to shuffle the inputs separately at each epoch, so that a 40 timestep sequence doesn't end up with the same 80 timestep sequence every time (the built in model.fit(shuffle = True) permutes the inputs in the same order).

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
for q in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    print(f'Epoch {q}...')

    pTrain = np.random.permutation(len(XTrain80))

    model.fit([XTrain80, XTrain40[pTrain]], [yTrain80, yTrain40[pTrain]], epochs = 1, shuffle = True)
```

Is there a better way to do this, preferably on one line?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to shuffle the inputs separately at each epoch while training your Siamese Neural Network for times series classification with two different lengths, you can achieve this by shuffling the indices separately for the two datasets(XTrain80 and XTrain40) and then using these shuffled indices to get the shuffled data. Please find this code.
`indices_80 = np.random.permutation(len(XTrain80))
indices_40 = np.random.permutation(len(XTrain40))
model.fit([XTrain80[indices_80], XTrain40[indices_40]], [yTrain80[indices_80], yTrain40[indices_40]], epochs=1)`